# Multi-regression model validation

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, descriptive-statistics, supervised-learning

I'm a new-bee in the ML modelling and have created a multi-linear regression model. I have got the rmse score for the model as approximately 5. How am I suppose to interpret this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Root Mean Squared Error is the square root of summed squared errors.  It is in a way an "expected error".  You could say "on average, the error between the observed data and the model prediction will be 5 units".  Could it be smaller/larger?  Yes.  But *on average* it would be 5.